# Regularity for a bipartite graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Let $G$ be a bipartite graph with $2^n$ left vertices and $2^n$ right vertices such that:

1) degree of every vertex is not greater then $2^t$

2) number of all edges is greater than $2^{n +t - O(\log n)}$.

Is it true that for every $d >0$ there is a subgraph $G_1 \subseteq G$ such that:

1) Every vertex that belongs to $G$ with degree at least $2^{t- d\log n}$ belongs also to $G_1$.

2) For every $s<t$ there are at most $2^{n-s + h\log n}$ vertices in $G_1$ that have degree at most $2^{t-s}$? Here $h = h(d)$.